# Android URL Content to String

Tags: android

I would like to connect to a Website, filter some content and then put it in a String but I don´t know how to do this.

```
public void zahlenLaden (View view) throws Exception { 

    URL oracle = new URL("http://www.blabla.de");
    URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(
                            yc.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
  //What I have to write here?
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare a String to output to before the while loop:

```
String output = "";
```

Then just append to that String in each iteration:

```
output += inputLine + "\n"; (don't forget the omitted newline)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

 while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
      sb.append(inputLine + "\n");

    }
```

then just do `sp.toString();`

Answer (score 0):

Nikola's answer is OK, just an improvement on the use of StringBuilder:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

 while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
      sb.append(inputLine).append("\n");
 }
```